# Spring Cloud DataFlow Rabbit Source: how to intercept and enrich messages in a Source

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I have been successfully evaluating Spring Cloud DataFlow with a typically simple flow: source | processor | sink.

For deployment there will be multiple sources feeding into this pipeline which I can do using data flow labels. All well and good.

Each source is a different rabbitmq instance and because the processor needs to know where the message came from (because it has to call back to the source system to get further information), the strategy I'd thought of was to enrich each message with header details about the source system which is then transparently passed along to the processor.

Now, I'm well-versed in Spring, Spring Boot and Spring Integration but I cannot find out how to enrich each message in a dataflow **source** component.

The source component is bound to an org.springframework.cloud.stream.app.rabbit.source.RabbitSourceConfiguration. The source uses the default Source.OUTPUT channel. How do I get hold of each message in the source to enrich it?

My processor component uses some Spring Integration DSL to do some of what it needs to do but then this processor component has both an INPUT and OUTPUT channel by definition. Not so with the RabbitSourceConfiguration source.

So, can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a custom `MessageListener` on the `MessageListenerContainer` in RabbitSourceConfiguration.

In the `RabbitSourceConfiguration` you can set a custom `ChannelAwareMessageListener` (You can possibly extend from `MessagingMessageListenerAdapter` as well) on the `MessageListenerContainer` that does what you incline to do.

Answer (score 0):

In the end what worked was subclassing org.springframework.cloud.stream.app.rabbit.source.RabbitSourceConfiguration to:

- override public SimpleMessageListenerContainer container() so that I could insert a custom health check before calling super.container(). My business logic enriches each message (see next bullet) with details of where the message came from (note, this is the publisher of the messages and not the rabbit queue). There's a health check needed to validate the additional enriching information (which is provided via configuration) to ensure that messages aren't consumed from the queue and enriched with the wrong information. If the validation fails, the source component fails to start and hence no messages are consumed.
- override the creation of the AmqpInboundChannelAdapter bean so that a custom subclass of DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper can be set on the adapter. This custom mapper adds the enriched headers in public Map toHeadersFromRequest(final MessageProperties source).

For me, the inability of stream/dataflow to intercept and modify messages in Source components is problematic. I really shouldn't have to fiddle around with the underlying message broker API in the ways I did. I should be able to do it with e.g. Spring Integration. Indeed I can register a global message interceptor but I cannot change the headers of the message.

This ability would go on my WIBNI (wouldn't it be nice if) list. Perhaps I'll raise a request for this.